# Random RAM usage amounts

Tags: c#, .net

I was hoping someone could explain why my application when loaded uses varying amounts of RAM.  I'm speaking about a compiled version that uses the exe directly.  It's a pretty basic applications and there are no conditional branches in the startup of the application.  Yet every time I start it up the RAM amount varies from 6MB-16MB.

I know it's on the small end of usage anyways but I'm curious of why this happens.

Edit: to give a bit more clarification on what the app actually does.
It is a WinForm project.
It connects to a database using sqlclient to retrieve a list of servers.
Based on that list a series of buttons are created to start and stop a service on those servers.
Using the System.Timers class to audit the status of the services on those servers every 20 seconds.
The applications at this point sits there and waits for user input via one of the button clicks to start/stop the service.

Comment: Maybe you could say what your application does, even better provide some sample code.

Comment: Need code.  When you say "pretty basic application" I imagine `Console.WriteLine("Hallo Wurlds!");`

Comment: Are you comparing cold start vs hot starts?

Comment: What performance counter do you refer to as "RAM amount"?

Comment: I edited the question to provide more information.  It's a main form and 2 dlls.  It involves threading, sql connection and windows authentication impersonator but the purpose is quite simple to start/stop a service on a remote server.  

And I'm using Memory (Private Working Set) from task manager.

I can't really provide any meaningful code as it is 500+ lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick here is that the amount of RAM reported by the task schedule is *not* the amount of RAM used by your application.  Rather, it is the amount of RAM *reserved* for use by your application.

Remember that with managed frameworks like .Net, you don't request or release memory directly.  Rather, a garbage collector manages the memory for you.  The amount of memory reserved for your application at a given time can vary and depends on a *lot* of different factors, including memory pressure created at the time by other programs.

Think of it this way: if you need 10 MBs of RAM for your app, is it faster to request and return it to the operating system 1 MB at a time over 10 requests/releases or reserve the block at once with one request/release?  Now extend that to a scenario where you don't know exactly how much RAM you'll need, only that it's somewhere in the neighborhood of 10 MB.  Additionally, your computer has 1 GB sitting there unused.  Of course the best thing to do is take a good-sized chunk of that available RAM. Even 20 or 30 MB wouldn't be unreasonable relative to the ram that's sitting there unused, because unused RAM is wasted performance.

If your system later starts to feel some memory pressure then .Net can easily return some RAM to the system. This is one of the ways managed languages can sometimes give *better* performance than languages like C++ with traditional memory management: a garbage collector that can more easily take the entire system health into account when allocating memory.

Answer (score 1):

What are you using to determine how much memory is being "used". Even with regular applications Windows will aggressively allocate unused memory in advance, with .NET applications it's even more complicated as to how much memory is actually being used, and how much Windows is just tacking on so that it will be available instantly when needed. If another application actually asks for memory this reserved memory will be repurposed.

One way to check is to minimize the application (at least on XP). If you are looking at the memory use in something like task manager you'll notice it drops off right away, eliminating the seemly "random" amount allocated.

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to the jitter, after the first load the jitter already created a compiled version and it doesn't need to run. Other than that you would have to give us some more details about the app and which kind of memory you are referring to.